Finding second positive number in row
The formula I used below allows me to find the first positive number in the row. I cant seem to get it to help me find the second positive number after. I would also need it to find the third, fourth, fifth, and so on.
=INDEX($J$8:$S$8,MATCH(1,INDEX(--($J$8:$S$8>0),1,0),0))


Do you have FILTER() function? If not can you try using INDEX()+AGGREGATE() like this way:-> =INDEX(FILTER(J8:S8,(J8:S8>0),0),2) or =INDEX($J$8:$S$8,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN($J$8:$S$8)-COLUMN($J$8)+1)/($J$8:$S$8>0),2))

Maybe worth mentioning that without wrapping it in INDEX it spills all positives (using Office 365), which may be the end goal.

This formula works in older versions Excel too. In cell I9 is the n-th positive number needed.
=INDEX(J8:S8,1,SMALL(IF(J8:S8>0,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},MAX(J8:S8)+1),I9))


If I have understood correctly, can you try something like this as below:
The following formula gives you the next positive numbers:


• Using FILTER()
=INDEX(FILTER(J8:S8,(J8:S8>0),0),2)


• Using INDEX()+AGGREGATE()
=INDEX($J$8:$S$8,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN($J$8:$S$8)-COLUMN($J$8)+1)/($J$8:$S$8>0),2))


• Using TOCOL()+CHOOSEROWS()
=CHOOSEROWS(TOCOL(J8:S8/(J8:S8>0),2),2)


The following formulas will give you the second positive number:

Or For the second positive number from the range:
=LARGE(FILTER(J8:S8,(J8:S8>0),0),2)


Or Using INDEX()+AGGREGATE()
=INDEX($J$8:$S$8,AGGREGATE(14,7,(COLUMN($J$8:$S$8)-COLUMN($J$8)+1)/($J$8:$S$8>0),1))


Or,
=LARGE(TOCOL(J8:S8/(J8:S8>0),2),2)


